# Image extending beyond div tag

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a grid of 12 div tags, each with an image in the middle. This works on most monitors, but my client has an ultra wide 34 inch monitor. On this, the divs will stretch out as expected, but each image scales beyond the confines of the divs. Any idea how to stop that?

This is an example of one of the 12 divs

```
<div class="mainHeaders font-weight-bold"><h2>Store</h2><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Have a game to sell? Click here! <img src="/images/pacman.png" alt="" style="width: 20px;"></a></div>
<div class="row" id="gamerow">
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/sega.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
          @foreach($segaCategories as $sega)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $sega->id)}}">{{ucfirst($sega->name)}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/nintylogo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="font-size: 0.7rem;">
          @foreach($nintCategories as $nint)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $nint->id)}}">{{ucfirst($nint->name)}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/pslogo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($psCategories as $ps)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $ps->id)}}">{{ucfirst($ps->name)}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/xboxlogo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid max-width: 100%">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">
          @foreach($xboxCategories as $xbox)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $xbox->id)}}">{{ucfirst($xbox->name)}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/amigalogo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($amigaCategories as $amiga)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $amiga->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/atarilogo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($atariCategories as $atari)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $atari->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="gamerow">
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <p id="eightBit">8-Bit</p>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($bitCategories as $bit)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $bit->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/3do.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($doCategories as $do)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $do->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/cdi.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($cdiCategories as $cdi)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $cdi->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/neo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($neoCategories as $neo)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $neo->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/pcengine.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($pcCategories as $pc)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $pc->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="import">Imports and other consoles</p>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($importCategories as $import)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $import->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="gamerow">
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories offset-md-4">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/cdi.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($cdiCategories as $cdi)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $cdi->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 gamesCategories">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/logos/neo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image img-fluid">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @foreach($neoCategories as $neo)
          <li><a href="{{route('games.show', $neo->id)}}">All&nbspGames</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the scss behind it:

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the object-fit property:

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

This will make sure your image fits in the parent div (but keep its original ratio).

Comment: they still go beyond the divs I'm afraid

Comment: Are you sure the divs have the correct size, then ? Check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/0eqxhnLb/ Is this not what you're looking for ?

Comment: I'm using the width from the bootstrap grid and fixed height of 150px

Comment: Could you share a larger portion of your code ? There is only one image in your example...

Comment: Ok, I've added the whole thing

Comment: Ok, I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ok5jcvtm/3/ Note: i've removed some elements like the overlay, to simplify the html. Also, there are some problems in your html, for example the button on top is closed with an </a> tag.

Comment: I think your problem may have come from the margin you put on the images. You can probably achieve what you want with padding on the container or margins on the 'row' divs.